# Scons to use Clang -MJ option

Tags: scons, clang++

Hi I am trying to build a compile_commands.json on windows with Scons build system and all other possibilities have failed.

I decided to use the Clang -MJ option to do this as this seems the easiest solution available.

The issue is that it isnt clear how I would go about doing this with the Scons build system; Basically I have to add `-MJ myfilename.o.json` to every build command. I am currently building a Library with multiple sources files like this :
`library = env.StaticLibrary(target=result_path + '/' + result_name, source=sources)`

Essentially at the end I should have : `clang++ -target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` **-MJ AABB.o.json** `-o src/core/AABB.o -c -m64 -g -O3 -std=c++14 -Wwrite-strings -I. -I/c/GodotLibraries/godot_headers -Iinclude -Iinclude/core src/core/AABB.cpp`

Thanks in advance,

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set special compiler flags for your current *build environment*. This is done by appending the new flags to the correct *environment variable*. Depending on what build process (=*Builder*) you want to use, the corresponding single build actions (=*Actions*) might use different variables. The [User Guide](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html) contains an Appendix A "Construction Variables", listing the default variables and their synopsis.

In your case the `CCFLAGS` is relevant and can be used like this:

```
env = Environment()
env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-MJ','AAB.o.json','-m64','-g','-O3'])

env.Program(...)
```

In the same way you can make *SCons* use the `clang` compiler, by setting the `CXX` variable accordingly:

```
env = Environment()
env['CXX']='clang'
env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-MJ','AAB.o.json','-m64','-g','-O3'])

env.Program(...)
```

I hope this lets you get the general idea behind the *Builder*/*Action* setup in *SCons*: The basic structure of the executed command is always the same for each *Builder*, but you can influence the final output by setting and overwriting those *environment variables* that get expanded.

Comment: Hi thank you for the fast response. The way to do it while keeping the name of the file was by adding this to the CPPFLAGS: '-MJ','${TARGET}.json'

Answer (score 1):

As of SCons 4.0.0, you can have SCons build the compilation database like this:

```
env.Tool('compilation_db')
env.CompilationDatabase('compile_commands.json')
```