# Linking with an specific shared library using its filename with Scons

Tags: shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, scons

I'm building a library with SCons.

The filename of a library that I want to be linked to doesn't start with the usual "lib" prefix.

I read ld documentation and check in my console running GCC that, if I put `-l:filename.so` a library named "filename.so" will be searched through the library paths specified.

When I try this solution into my SConscript file, apparently Scons keeps the colon in the front of the library name, but it removes the ".so" part, so the library cannot be found because its filename contains the .so extension.

Update: A brief example.

```
env = Environment()

hello = env.Program(["hello.cc"], LIBPATH=['.'], LIBS=[':kntlm.so'])
```

This Scons script try to compile the source "hello.cc" (only a Hello world, not using any library). In the same directory I copied, only for this example purpose, a library from my system. I named it "kntlm.so" instead its real name (libkntlm.so).

From a terminal, I can run this:

```
g++ -o hello hello.o -L. -l:kntlm.so
```

And GCC compiles it without any problem.

If I try to run Scons, I get the following executed:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o hello hello.o -L. -l:kntlm
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -l:kntlm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [hello] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

As you can see, the GCC that Scons executed include the "-l:kntlm", but it removed the ".so" from the end, so the library file cannot be found

Do you know how can I specify a filename for a library instead this weird substitution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please show us the current version of your SConstruct (strip it down to a minimal, but working, example)? It's a difference between the `LIBS` and `LDFLAGS` variables, so we have to know what you're trying exactly.

Comment: I'm using 2.0.0 (I cannot change to a newer version, it doesn't depend on me). I'll try to update the original messange with a brief example. Thank you for your response

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341906/scons-to-use-clang-mj-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items in the `LIBS` variable are meant to be the stem part of each of your libraries only. *SCons* will add a prefix and suffix (`LIBLINKPREFIX` and `LIBLINKSUFFIX`, respectively) to them automatically when compiling the final "link" command.

In your case you should simply add the "`-l:kntlm.so`" option to the variable `LINKFLAGS` directly:

```
env = Environment()

hello = env.Program(["hello.cc"], LIBPATH=['.'], LINKFLAGS=['-l:kntlm.so'])
```

Note, that this isn't platform-independent anymore...which is the whole point behind using the `LIBS` list under normal circumstances.

And yes, the [User Guide](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html) tells you to **not** set a "`-l`" option via the "`LINKFLAGS`", but this is an exception from the default rule.

Finally, if you create shared libraries you'll have to use `SHLINKFLAGS` instead.

Comment: I have tested and it works, but it generated me a derived problem. Now, the dependency from "hello" objective with "kntlm.so" is not defined. In my real scenario, `kntlm.so` is a Scons-generated library too, in another directory. How can I the "hello" objective to depend from the other library generation?

Comment: Check section 6.5 "Explicit Dependencies: the Depends Function" in the [User Guide](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html). By using the `Depends` method you can add the required link between your library and the executable.

Comment: Thanks! I finally used "Require" and a "File" objetive, because this library is compiled too, but it is "imported" from another project, so I need to "wait" for it to be compiled before start to compile my library. Thank you for pointing me correctly :-)